# show JDialog with animated gif while processing some work in background

Tags: java, swing, jdialog, swingworker

I am trying to create a `JDialog` which will shows an animated image till background process gets completed. I created a `JDialog` which shows the **Animated GIF** but when I put it before the actual process get started it shows only blank JDialog.

Here is my code:

> public void createDialog() 
> {
>        d=new JDialog();
>        JLabel l=new JLabel(new ImageIcon(new URL("path_of_icon")));
>        d.setSize(100,100);
>        d.add(l);
>        d.setVisible(true);
>        d.alwaysOnTop(true); 
> }
>
> //now how do I calling this function
>
> createDialog();
>  doBackgroundProcess();    //like fetching data from database
>   d.dispose();

Can anybody tell me how do I show the loading image without interrupting the background process. Do I need to use `SwingWorker` or `Thread`.

Comment: For better help sooner, please post a [Minimal Complete Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`SwingWorker` is your best choice**, because it will manage several threads for you.

Here is more about it http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html

UPDATE:

`doInBackground` is executed on a separate (not a UI) thread and usually used for a long non-UI process. Method `done` is executed on UI thread when the long process is finished. So create and show your dialog before creating `SwingWorker`. Than run your background process using `SwingWorker`, in `done` - hide the dialog.

Comment: do I need to make visible JDialog in `doInBackground()` method or I need to repaint it. I'm quite confused.